# The method of creating a function works every period of time

Tags: java, android

How do I do a job
Works every period of time
Example :
I have text and I want the text to change every five seconds forever
How do I do it?

Comment: Probably by doing some research, reading tutorials, writing code, and trying yourself. Not by asking us to explain stuff to you that is well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with handler.postDelayed() method.

```
private void doTask(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your stuff here
            doTask();
        }
    }, 1000);  //time interval 
}
```

Comment: What problem was there when you add this code? & you must use android.os.Handler not java.util.logging.Handler, keep this in mind.